# Progress reporting in Haskell Tasty tests

Tags: haskell, testing, tasty, progress-reports

I have a bunch of tests in my `tasty` test suite. Currently `tasty` runs all the tests and then print out the results all at once, e.g.

```bash
Tests
  DeBruijnIndices
    substUnderLambdaClosed:       OK
    liftUnderLambdaOpenType:      OK
  Normalisation
    normaliseLambda:              OK
    normaliseAppLambdaClosedBody: OK
    normaliseAppLambdaOpenBody:   OK
```

However, sometimes I create an infinite loop by accident and one of the tests fails to terminate. In this case `tasty` never prints anything, even though it's running the tests in a multi-threaded environment. This makes it impossible to diagnose which test is the problem.

Is there someway to make `tasty` print out the intermediate progress on the tests? The first entry of the [CHANGELOG for v1.5](https://github.com/UnkindPartition/tasty/blob/master/core/CHANGELOG.md#version-15) suggests there might be but I have no idea how to hook into it, and there doesn't seem to be any examples or documentation provided.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? [With a small test, tasty already seems to print completed tests before starting the next one.](https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/fcd816921f6e3153f7fcf0971eddc1ff) So something else is going wrong. What version of tasty are you using? How are you running the tests?

Comment: Have you tried invoking it like this, using the "show streaming details" option? `cabal test --test-show-detail=streaming`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `cabal test tests --test-show-detail=streaming`

Apparently in the future (likely 3.12) a new detail level will be the defailt, namely `direct` which is like streaming but it does not create a log file but does have colored output:

https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-commands.html#cmdoption-runhaskell-Setup.hs-test-test-show-details

Alternatively you could use `cabal run tests`, which runs the tests as a normal executable.

Comment: Ah fantastic, thank you! Didn't realise it was a cabal option I was looking for and not a tasty one!